# ASP.NET Core only returning first value of a collection in an entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class MyEntity with a collection within it:

```
public class MyEntity
{    
    [Key]
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Process Name")]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Step> ProcessSteps { get; set; }
}
```

A one-many relationship with class Step:

```
public class Step
{
    ...
    [ForeignKey("MyEntityForeignKey")]
    public MyEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the API call to return a specified MyEntity:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyEntity(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return Ok(await _context.MyEntity.ToListAsync());
    }

    var process = _context.MyEntity.Where(f => f.MyId == id).Include(g => g.ProcessSteps);

    if (process.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(process.First());
}
```

When running this, everything looks great except for the collection. While debugging, the correct values are shown. Even though I have 2+ items in these collections, it always returns just the first item in the ProcessSteps collection from MyClass when it returns the response *Ok*.

**Edit:**

It looks like returning the response with my foreign key attached was the culprit. Iterating through and nulling the foreign key seems to have fixed things.

```
foreach (Step step in MyEntity.ProcessSteps)
{
     Step.MyEntity = null;
}

return Ok(MyEntity.ProcessSteps)
```

Comment: If you place a break point right after `var process` and inspect the object in memory, do multiple items show up under `ProcessSteps`?

Comment: Not necessarily related, but you should use `FirstOrDefault()` and check for `null` instead of running `Count()` first and then `First()` later again. Latter will run two queries.

Comment: @NateBarbettini `process` is just an queryable that hasn’t been executed yet, so nothing is loaded from the database.

Comment: Can you show your database context configuration to see how the mapping from `MyEntity` to `Step` is configured?

Comment: @NateBarbettini it does show multiple items when debugging. It's only in the JSON output that it returns a single value for ProcessSteps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where only the first entity of the target collection was returned unless I was setting to null all the inner references.
 However I was able to solve this by mapping my model to dto object (or ViewModel) before returning it. The dto has usually a subset of the model entity. In this way I did not have to set to null the inner references.
In general I think it is a good practice to **return to the client only the properties that are strictly needed**, without giving the whole model object.