# EF Core returns only first record of a list unless FK entities are reset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am facing the same issue as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731056/asp-net-core-only-returning-first-value-of-a-collection-in-an-entity). 
**Problem:** my method `GetAllConferences()` returns correctly all the conferences from the DB, but when I return the result to the View from the controller `return Ok(tripListVm)` inly the first collection item is returned to the client. 
 On the otehr side, by setting to null all the FK references (as pointed out in the SO question above) I can return correctly all the entities to the client, however this does not seem to me the proper way of proceeding. 
**EDIT:** the solution was much simpler than I though. In the code below (I leave it in its original form for others to see it) I was not mapping the FK entities inside the ViewModel to Dto objects, but returning the model entity itself. That was the reason why I needed to null those inner references to make it work. 
By returning all Dtos objects, it works properly.

I have three entities involved with 1-many relationships:

```
public class Conference
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Venue> Venues { get; set; }

    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
 }

public class Venue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ConferenceId { get; set; }
    public Trip Conference { get; set; }

    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
 }

public class City 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Conference> Conferences { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
 }
```

In the repository, I have a method that returns the conferences and the related entities (City and Venues):

```
 public IEnumerable<Conference> GetAllConferences()
 {   
    return _context.Conferences
                   .Include(t => t.Venues)
                   .Include(t => t.City)
                   .ToList();
 }
```

In the controller I need to use the following code to return all the results:

```
 var conferences = _repository.GetAllConferences();
 if (conferences.Any())
 {
    var conferenceListVm = trips.ToConferenceVmList();

    //Without setting the FK references to null, I can return only the first result of the collection

    foreach (var vm in conferenceListVm)
    {
       foreach (var pm in vm.PoinOfInterests)
       {
          pm.Trip = null;
       }

       vm.Location.Conferences = null;
       vm.Location.Venues = null;
    }

  return Ok(conferenceListVm);
}

public static ConferenceViewModel ToConferenceVm(this Conference conference)
{
   var confVm = new ConferenceViewModel();
   confVm.Name = conference.Name;

   confVm.City = conference.City; 
   confVm.Venues = conference.Venues;

   return tripVm;
}

public static IEnumerable<ConferenceViewModel> ToConferenceVmList(this IEnumerable<Conference> conferences)
{
   return conferences.Select(c => c.ToConferenceVm()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I  don't get your issue. Do you mean that trpListVm collection only returns the first item in the list? What is the  implementation of TOTripVmList() method and GetAllTrips() method.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I updated the questions to make it more clear (thanks to point it out) and added the mapper code (I prefer to use my own mapper classes than AutoMapper).